# How to change image of a component in radlistview on tap event

Tags: nativescript

I have a radlist view with some radio button like image on its child

```
 <lv:RadListView row="2" items="{{ choices_list }}" loaded="onLoaded" selectionBehavior="Press" multipleSelection="false" itemLoading="onItemLoading" itemTap="onItemTap">
                        <lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
                            <GridLayout rows="*" borderRadius="5" columns="auto,*" class="bgws p-20" margin="20 0 0 0">
                                <Image col="0" id="radio_button" src="~/images/radio.png" stretch="fill" />
                                <Label col="1" text="{{ $value }}" class="fs18 font2" textWrap="true" />
                            </GridLayout>
                        </lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
                    </lv:RadListView>
```

the array I'm passing to this is `choices_list: ["300 m", "30 m", "3 m", "0.3 m"],`

On Press by default it changes the color of cell to some light color. but, i need a way to change  image `~/images/radio.png` to `~/images/tick.png`

on item tap i'm calling a function

```
exports.onItemTap = function(args) {
    console.log(args.view.bindingContext);
}
```

***important*** 
i cannot change the format of array I'm passing

Comment: Ideally you want to have the state of the list in the array that you pass in.
and then when you want to send the data to the API, you can convert it back to the desired form.
If you don't take this approach, you will inevitably end up with other issues.
(if you don't know what I mean, read this: https://www.nativescript.org/blog/managing-component-state-in-nativescript-listview)

Comment: You must change your data format to easily keep track of ones those are tapped vs those are not. You are not suppose to modify the view directly.

Comment: @ShivaPrasad ok, I'll change the array to object locally and use it. Thank you.